# Scale images to Android device size

Tags: android, image, view, android-activity

Currently developing an android game.
Right now all of my images are based around a resolution of 480x320.
However, when I draw this on my device, it's actually smaller than what I expected.

In eclipse, I put my 480x320 image in my drawable-hdpi folder.
I thought it would stretch across the entire screen/view, but it unfortunately does not.

How do I make it so my View scales all images inside it to fit my device resolution?
Is there an option in my Android manifest I need to edit? Or something I need to do in my View class?

Comment: PS: I am not using a game engine, just straight using the Android SDK.

Bitmap bmp =     BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.background);
  
canvas.drawBitmap(bmp, 0, 0, paint);

Comment: I think you should move it to a lower res file if you want it to stretch, or of course the better option is to provide as many versions as needed.

Comment: I did this. Moved my 480x320 background image to the res/drawable-ldpi folder. However, not it doesnt show the entire image. It gets cut off (the image appears larger than the device screen now).

Comment: It's trying to do the best it can with what you gave it.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want android to mess with your drawables you should use the drawable folder or the assets folder. That said I think we need some code samples as I have a feeling something else is wrong :)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe `Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bmp, width, height, false);' would be useful?